# Program not running the same when using goto

Tags: c, scanf

Hi I am brand new to programming in C.  I am trying to create a calculator.  I succeeded in doing this but when I try to make the program start over so the user can ask another question it does not work correctly.  It looks something like this

```
Type what operation you want to do(+, -, *, /:)
*
Enter two operands:
 8
8
The product of the two numbers is64
Type what operation you want to do(+, -, *, /:)
Enter two operands:
 gg
Type what operation you want to do(+, -, *, /:)
Enter two operands:
 Type what operation you want to do(+, -, *, /:)
Enter two operands:
```

It skips the first line of input and for however many characters I type it does the same thing.  Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  start:;
  char operator;
  int a, b, sum, differnce, product, quotient;
  printf("Type what operation you want to do(+, -, *, /:)\n");
  scanf("%c", &operator);

  printf("Enter two operands:\n " );
  scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

  switch(operator)
  {
    case '+':
      sum = a + b;
      printf("The sum of the two numbers is:%d\n",sum);
      break;
    case '-':
      differnce = a - b;
      printf("The differnce of the two numbers is:%d\n",differnce);
      break;
    case '*':
      product = a * b;
      printf("The product of the two numbers is%d\n",product);
      break;
    case '/':
      quotient = a / b;
      printf("The quotient of the two numbers is %d\n", quotient);
      break;
  }
  goto start;
  return 0;
}
```

Now I know the goto command is not very good so if there is an alternative that would work I'm open to it.

Comment: Always a recipe for surprises: not testing the return value from scanf().

Comment: and `scanf("%c", &operator);` --> `scanf(" %c", &operator);`

Comment: use fflush(stdin)

Comment: @PritamKarmakar Don't use `fflush(stdin)`. It has undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks Bluepixy your solution worked. if someone could explain why that extra space worked that would be awesome.

Comment: @Zackattak01 Short version: Never use `scanf` for user input. There are more hidden surprises lurking in your code.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks.  As for the scanf what should I use?

Comment: `goto` has its applications. But this is none of them! Use a loop statement!

Comment: @Zackattak01 Use `fgets` to read a complete line from `stdin`. If you need to convert it into a number, use e.g. `strtol` or `sscanf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you read a `char` you should clean your buffer. 
Don't [use `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) — it is a bad practice.
You can add this function instead:

```
void clean_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

and call it after the `scanf:

```
 scanf("%c", &operator);
 clean_stdin();`
```

About the GOTO: you can use a loop — probably a `while` loop or perhaps a  `for` loop or `do … while` loop instead.  These are easier to understand than using `goto` statements and labels.

**Update**

Or, as @BLUEPIXIE suggests, you can change your `scanf` in this way:

```
scanf(" %c", &operator); // adding a space before %c
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually not the `goto` statement but the fact that a `scanf("%c",...)` will consume a new line, which is probably in the in-buffer after a previously entered integral value.

Suppose the following code:

```
int main() {

    char operator;
    int a;

    printf("Enter an integral value:\n " );
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Try to enter an operator (will probably be skipped):\n " );
    scanf("%c", &operator);

    if (operator == '\n')
        printf("You entered a new line (did you?)\n");
    else
        printf("You entered: %c\n", operator);

    return 0;
}
```

If you enter an integral value and press `<enter>`, then a new line character will remain in the buffer. This is immediately consumed by the subsequent `scanf`-statement. So if you enter, for example; `19` and press `<enter>`, then you'll get the following output:

```
Enter an integral value: 19
Try to enter an operator (will probably be skipped):
 You entered a new line (did you?)
```

However, if you use - as suggested by melpomene - the following statement:

```
scanf(" %c", &operator);
```

then `scanf` will consume an arbitrary long sequence of white space characters (including new lines) before actually reading in the first non-white-space character into `%c->&operator`:

```
Enter an integral value:
 19
Enter an operator:


+
You entered: +
```